# Can we find a unique probability Borel measurable $\mu$ on $\mathcal{C}$ with $\mu(N_s)=\phi(s)$

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

If $\phi:2^{<\mathbb{N}}\to [0,1]$ satisfies $\phi(\emptyset)=1$ and $\phi(s)=\phi(s^{\widehat{}}0)+\phi(s^{\widehat{}}1)$ for all $s \in 2^{<\mathbb{N}}$.

Can we find a unique probability Borel measurable $\mu$ on $\mathcal{C}=2^{\mathbb{\omega}}$ with $\mu(N_s)=\phi(s)$ where $N_s=\{x\in 2^{\mathbb{N}}: s \subseteq x \}$ for $s \in 2^{<\mathbb{N}}$.

Can anybody give me any hint how one might prove this?. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The uniqueness is a standard monotone class or $\pi$-$\lambda$ argument.  Suppose $\mu, \mu'$ are two Borel measures satisfying the desired condition.  Let $\mathcal{P} = \{N_s : s \in 2^{<\mathbb{N}}\}$; clearly $\mu, \mu'$ agree for all sets in $\mathcal{P}$.  You can verify that $\mathcal{P}$ is a $\pi$-system, i.e. closed under intersections, and that it generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $2^\omega$.  Then let $\mathcal{L}$ be the collection of all Borel sets on which $\mu, \mu'$ agree.  You can show that $\mathcal{L}$ is a $\lambda$-system, and then the [$\pi$-$\lambda$ lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system) lets you conclude that $\mathcal{L}$ contains all the Borel sets.

The existence is a special case of the Kolmogorov extension theorem.  There are many different ways to state this theorem but a useful one for us looks like this:

> Let $X$ be a standard Borel space.  For each $n$, let $\mu_n$ be a Borel probability measure on the finite product $X^n$.  Suppose that for each $n$ and each Borel set $B \subset X^n$, we have the consistency condition $\mu_n(B) = \mu_{n+1}(B \times X)$.  Then there is a Borel probability measure on the infinite product $X^\omega$ which extends all the $\mu_n$: for each $n$ and each Borel $B \subset X^n$, we have $\mu_n(B) = \mu(B \times X \times X \times \cdots)$.

You can find a proof in [these lecture notes of mine](http://www.unco.edu/NHS/mathsci/facstaff/Eldredge/6710/6710-lecture-notes.pdf) (Theorem 10.8), in the "special" case $X = I = [0,1]$ (the general case follows because every standard Borel space is measurably embedded in $[0,1]$).

Of course we want to apply the theorem with $X = 2$.  For each $n$, define the measure $\mu_n$ on subsets of $2^n$ by $\mu_n(A) = \sum_{s \in A} \phi(s)$.    The conditions you have given on $\phi$ will guarantee that each $\mu_n$ is a probability measure and that the Kolmogorov consistency condition is satisfied.  Now the measure $\mu$ supplied by Kolmogorov's theorem is your desired measure.  (I will leave it to you to verify the details.)

As a general rule, any time you want to produce a measure on an infinite dimensional space, you should look to this theorem.  It's by far the most commonly used tool for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Nate Eldrige's answer is probably better than mine. I'm leaving mine here anyway in case anyone wants a hint how to do it "by hand"...

I take it $s^j$ is the same as what one might (less correctly but perhaps more intuitively) write $(s,j)$? Assuming so:

Seems not entirely trivial, but fairly routine. Say $A$ is the *algebra* (not sigma-algebra) generated by the $N(s)$. Show that $A$ is equal to the set of all finite disjoint unions of the $N(s)$. That tells you what $\mu(E)$ should be for $E\in A$. Of course you need to show that $\mu$ is well-defined.

Now the slightly tricky part is showing that $\mu$ is a *premeasure* on $A$. Meaning that if it *happens* that a set in $A$ is a countable disjoint union of sets in $A$ then the measures add up. You easily reduce this to the case of one of the $N(s)$ being a countable disjoint union of other $N(s)$'s; the tricky part is that that can be a more complicated union than you may realize at first.

(Although it's less tricky than I thought; less tricky than various similar things: Say $N(s)$ is the disjoint union of the $N(s_j)$. Now $N(s)$ is compact, being a closed subset of $2^\omega$, and each $N(s_j)$ is open...)

Now a theorem of Caratheodory shows that $\mu$ extends to a measure on $\mathcal A$, the sigma-algebra generated by $A$. Show that $\mathcal A$ is the Borel algebra.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the "show this is a premeasure" part is the Kolmogorov extension theorem.

Comment: @NateEldredge Hmm. I never paid any attention to that KET thing except in the special case of product measures. Paying attention to it for a minute, yes I believe you're right. Except that if _I'm_ not mistaken KET actually does the whole problem, without worrying about any Caratheodory stuff. ???

Comment: Yeah, I didn't say that very clearly.  You're right, the usual statement of KET does do the whole thing (see my answer below).  But the usual *proof* of KET is to invoke Caratheodory, with the hard part being to verify the "premeasure" hypothesis.

Comment: Incidentally, the key part of the "slightly tricky part" is going to rely on the compactness of $2^\omega$, or something of the kind.  It's more subtle than one might think.

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed. No, wait. I've been thinking of all this as equivalent to something about half-open intervals; the tricky part there is indeed more subtle than one might think. But wait, it's not quite equivalent. And in fact right now this seems much easier than I thought: Say $N(s)$ is the disjoint union of the $N(s_j)$. That's an open cover of a compact space... qed.

Comment: It's certainly simpler in this case, because the topology on the space $2$ is... simpler.  But I don't think it's going to occur to the average student to use compactness here, especially because there is no topology apparent in the statement.  And the compactness of $2^\omega$, while standard, is not quite trivial.

Comment: @NateEldredge Agreed.